# Xamarin Forms: Google map doesn't show even after signing the application on android

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin

I am changing sample Xamarin application which shows how to use Maps (WorkingWithMaps)

I created an APIKey using these steps: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key

and added it to AndroidManifest.xml as follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.workingwithmaps" android:installLocation="preferExternal">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="28" />
    <application android:label="WorkingWithMaps.Android">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY" android:value="I ADD MY KEY HERE" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <!-- Necessary for apps that target Android 9.0 or higher -->
        <uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
</manifest>
```

then as explained here, I created a Keystore certificate and used is for signing my application for debugging:

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/23650/is-there-problem-google-map-services

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/29053/google-map-doesnt-show-anything

and now the application csprj has these entries:

```
 <AndroidSigningKeyStore>C:\Users\Mansour\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\Keystore\samplekey\samplekey.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
<AndroidSigningStorePass>pass1</AndroidSigningStorePass>
<AndroidSigningKeyAlias>samplekey</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
<AndroidSigningKeyPass>pass1</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
```

But still, the map doesn't show.

What should I do?

I read somewhere that the application should have INTERNET permission, but since this is the sample application which is provided as part of XAMARIN, I thought it is set up to have INTERNET permission. Am I wrong?

## Edit 1

Logs when I run the application on a Lenovo yoga tablet which I think is related to this error:

```
03-10 10:04:21.712 E/Google Maps Android API(26347): Authorization failure.  Please see https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start for how to correctly set up the map.
03-10 10:04:21.718 E/Google Maps Android API(26347): In the Google Developer Console (https://console.developers.google.com)
03-10 10:04:21.718 E/Google Maps Android API(26347): Ensure that the "Google Maps Android API v2" is enabled.
03-10 10:04:21.718 E/Google Maps Android API(26347): Ensure that the following Android Key exists:
03-10 10:04:21.718 E/Google Maps Android API(26347):    API Key: ****SyBUI3fDPsFZBLMA5JjxGm--VDygTspSv6c
03-10 10:04:21.718 E/Google Maps Android API(26347):    Android Application (<cert_fingerprint>;<package_name>): 37:F3:F0:27:92:FD:20:93:90:A6:DA:4E:4A:20:3D:A0:5B:22:57:D3;com.companyname.workingwithmaps
```

I checked the cloud,google.com and setting for this key is unrestricted:

[image]

What else should I do?

Comment: look at the log output when your app launches to see if there are any error messages related to maps

Comment: First of all, please download this demo zip from this thread. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithmaps/ do not change others place, refer to this thread step by step to get the API_KEY

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=windows#obtaining-your-signing-key-fingerprint
Note: please enable the Maps SDK for Android in the google console.

Comment: @Jason I looked at the logs and extract the section which I believe is related. I am not sure how I can fix the problem, as from my point of view, both suggestion solution is already checked.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I did as you suggested and get the same result. The log shows the same error as shown above in the question

Comment: @mans Please set the Application restrictions to Android apps in google console like my screenshot https://imgur.com/a/uUMRvSm, Please follow this thread step by step,do not change others settings:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=windows#obtaining-your-signing-key-fingerprint

Comment: @mans Are there any update for this issue?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Your suggestion lead me to look if I enabled Android Map SDK and after enabling it, the application works.  Please upgrade your comment to an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: @mans I wirte an answer, please accept it, it will help others who have similar issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, please download this demo zip from this thread.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/workingwithmaps/

Then refer to this thread step by step to get the `API_KEY`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=windows#obtaining-your-signing-key-fingerprint

Note: enable the Maps SDK for Android in the google console. 
[image]

And select the `Android apps` in the Application restrictions, do not set the `none`.

If you set the `Android apps`, you need to set the [SHA-1 value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/platform/maps-and-location/maps/obtaining-a-google-maps-api-key?tabs=windows#obtaining-your-signing-key-fingerprint) and your android package name like following thread.

[image]